# How to apply a function to each element of a list of chars

Tags: list, function, haskell

I would like to test an input String if its verified by a few conditions. I got stuck when i need to apply a function to the rest of the list elements. How should i approach this situation?

My code looks like:

```
import Data.Char

listLower = ['a'..'z']
listUpper = ['A'..'Z']
listNum = ['0'..'9']
listRes = ["if","then","else","module","import"]


isIdentifierStart :: Char -> Bool
isIdentifierStart x = x `elem` listLower
isIdentifierStart _ = False

isIdentifierPart :: Char -> Bool
isIdentifierPart x = x `elem` listLower || x `elem` listUpper || x `elem` listNum
isIdentifierPart _ = False

isReserved :: String -> Bool
isReserved x = x `elem` listRes
isReserved _ = False

isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid (x:xs) = (isIdentifierStart x) && (isIdentifierPart xs) && (not (isReserved [x]))
```

And the error message i got :

```
hf4.hs:22:61: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the first argument of ‘isIdentifierPart’, namely ‘xs’
      In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(isIdentifierPart xs)’
      In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely
        ‘(isIdentifierPart xs) && (not (isReserved [x]))’
   |
22 | isValid (x:xs) = (isIdentifierStart x) && (isIdentifierPart xs) && (not (isReserved [x]))    |
```

Comment: With `map`, but here you probably want to use `any` or `all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems here. You here define a function `isValid` that takes a string. This thus means that `x` is the first character of the string, and `xs` are the remaining characters.

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid (x:xs) = isIdentifierStart x && all isIdentifierPart xs
```

You furthermore want to call `isReserved` on the *entire* string. We can do that by making use of an "*as-pattern*".

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid xa@(x:xs) = isIdentifierStart x && all isIdentifierPart xs && not (isReserved xa)
```

Finally we need to cover the empty string case here. If an empty string is considered not valid, we can write this as:

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid "" = False
isValid xa@(x:xs) = isIdentifierStart x && all isIdentifierPart xs && not (isReserved xa)
```